# how to write out a list variable with the original format

Tags: list, tcl

In TCL, there is an array var defined.

```
set array_var(a1) "this is a string, not list"
set array_var(a2) [list a b c d e]
set array_var(a3) [list { "aa" "bb" } { "bb" "cc" }]
```

I want to write out array_var definition which can be source back later.

```
foreach key [array names array_var] {
    set nameString [format %s(%s) array_var $key]
    puts $SI_fh "set $nameString \"$array_var($key)\""
}
```

How to generate output file just as original definition with and without "`[list` "?

Comment: When asking a code related question, it's important to add a tag for the language in which you're coding. Please [edit] your question to add one. Thanks. (Yes, I see the text says TCL, but a tag containing that information is better, as it gets the question in front of people who can answer your question. I didn't add it because you should learn how to [edit] your questions here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
set array_var(a1) "this is a string, not list"
set array_var(a2) [list a b c d e]
set array_var(a3) [list { "aa" "bb" } { "bb" "cc" }]
parray array_var
```

prints

```
array_var(a1) = this is a string, not list
array_var(a2) = a b c d e
array_var(a3) = { "aa" "bb" } { "bb" "cc" }
```

At this point, you can't go back and see how these values were created: the array elements contain just the values, not the history.

There are many ways to create these values:

```
list "this" "is" "a" "string," "not" "list"
string cat this " " is " " a " " string ", " not " " list
dict create this is a string, not list
```

And a string with an even number of space separated words is indistinguishable from a list with an even number of elements, or a dictionary value.

---

for storing the state of this array, I'd do

```
foreach {key value} [array get array_var] {
    puts [list set "array_var($key)" $value]
}
```

```
set array_var(a3) {{ "aa" "bb" } { "bb" "cc" }}
set array_var(a1) {this is a string, not list}
set array_var(a2) {a b c d e}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an array for later, and are *not particularly bothered about the stored format being very readable*, the simplest method is this (yes, `source`ing the file is how to load it back in):

```
puts $SI_fh [list array set array_var [array get array_var]]
```

The `array get` command serializes an array (without any traces, but that's usually not a problem at all) and `array set` takes the serialized form (which is a dictionary) and reinflates it back into an array. The `list` is because that creates exactly the quoting we want to make a substitution-free command (it's how the format of lists is defined to work).

The only disadvantage is that the format actually in the file is not optimised for humans, being something like this (the actual order is arbitrary; Tcl's arrays have never made order guarantees):

```
array set array_var {a2 {a b c d e} a1 {this is a string, not list} a3 {{ "aa" "bb" } { "bb" "cc" }}}
```